# Spaces in regular expression

Tags: python, regex

I have this code to find `:)` and `:(` in a text:

```
for match in re.finditer(r':\)|:\(', ":) :):( :)  :("):
    print  match.span()
```

and give me this answer:

```
(0, 2)
(3, 5)
(5, 7)
(8, 10)
(12, 14)
```

It works, but I need it to show me only those which the word is alone(next to no other character) so the answer would be:

```
(0, 2)
(8, 10)
(12, 14)
```

I tried adding `\b` but got no answer

This is a case to add **(x)** to the pattern

```
for match in re.finditer(r'(?<![\w()]):(?:\)|\()(?![\w:])', ":) :):( :)  :(  (x)"):
    print  match.span()
```

shows:

```
(0, 2)
(8, 10)
(12, 14)
```

ans I want

```
(0, 2)
(8, 10)
(12, 14)
(16, 19)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If by no other character, you mean no other visible character, so that the only characters allowed around the smiley are space (including tabs), you could use something like this:

```
for match in re.finditer(r"(?:(?<=\s)|(?<=^)):[()](?=\s|$)", ":) :):( :)  :("):
    print match.span()
```

`(?:(?<=\s)|(?<=^))` makes sure there's either a whitespace character or the beginning of the line before the smiley,

`:[()]` matches `:` followed by either `(` or `)`

`(?=\s|$)` makes sure that there's either a whitespace character or the end of the line after the smiley.

If you additionally want to match the smiley `x)`, you can use this:

```
r"(?:(?<=\s)|(?<=^))(?::[()]|x\))(?=\s|$)"
```

If you want to match `x(` as well, it becomes a little easier:

```
r"(?:(?<=\s)|(?<=^))[x:][()](?=\s|$)"
```

`[ ... ]` is a character class and you don't need to escape stuff in there. Be wary of the placements of `-` and `^` since those two have special meanings in a character class.

EDIT: Seems that I got the wrong additional smiley x) For this (meaning `:)`, `:(` and `(x)`), it will be something a bit like that:

```
r"(?:(?<=\s)|(?<=^))(?::[()]|\(x\))(?=\s|$)"
```

reEDIT: Actually, the positive assertions can be shortened with negative ones, which makes it simpler:

```
r"(?<!\S)(?::[()]|\(x\))(?!\S)"
```

Comment: I got `raise error, v # invalid expression` please review my question, I edited to explain a bit better.

Comment: @Andres Oops, I almost always forget that Python doesn't not support variable width lookbehind... I fixed that part and I did consider your edit.

Answer (score 3):

`:`, `(` and `)` are *non word characters*, so `\b` won't work. You'd use the inverse, `\B`:

```
r'\B:(?\)|\()\B'
```

Where `\b` matches on the boundary between `\w` and `\W` or vice-versa, `\B` only matches between two `\w` or two `\W` points. Since `:` and the parenthesis characters are both `\W` characters, this means they must sit next to another non-word character (or the start or end of the line).

This will still match *other* smileys too however.

To completely exclude other smileys you need to use both a negative look-ahead and a negative look-behind:

```
r'(?<![\w()]):(?\)|\()(?![\w:])'
```

This says:

- `(?<![\w()])`: No word character or parentheses before the smiley (start of string is fine)
- `(?![\w:])`: No word character or colon after the smiley (end of string is fine)

Demo:

```
>>> for match in re.finditer(r'(?<![\w()]):(?:\)|\()(?![\w:])', ":) :):( :)  :("):
...     print  match.span()
... 
(0, 2)
(8, 10)
(12, 14)
```

For your updated pattern version, you clearly don't mind if `(` is in front, so we remove that from the excluded characters preceding the pattern, and update `:` to `[x:]` to match either an `x` or a colon:

```
r'(?<![\w)])[x:](?:\)|\()(?![\w:])'
```

Demo:

```
>>> for match in re.finditer(r'(?<![\w)])[x:](?:\)|\()(?![\w:])', ":) :):( :)  :( (x)"):
...     print  match.span()
... 
(0, 2)
(8, 10)
(12, 14)
(16, 18)
```

Comment: what if I need to add another pattern? ie,**"(x)|:\)|:\("** instead of **":\)|:\("** . Do I need to implement another approach?

Comment: @Andres: As long as you can express what should *not* come before the smiley, it'll work. In that case, `x` is already part of `[\w()]` so should work just fine.